# Get Marker Feature Instance in MapBox

Tags: mapbox, marker

I'm new to mapbox GL JS and am following this example:
**Add custom markers in Mapbox GL JS**
https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers-gl-js/

Let's say I modify the example above to include 100 different animal markers. How do I change the draggable property of a specific marker after it has been added to the map?

Example: Change the draggable property of the dog marker.

It would be nice to do something like this:
    map.getMarker('dog').setDraggable(true);

I don't see a way to query any of the markers added to my map or modify a specific marker's properties like setLatLng, setDraggable after they have been added to a map.  There is no method to get the collection of markers added to a map.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I figured out your problem. But why don't you assign variable for your marker as a reference when you create it ?

Answer (score 0):

For change marker property like draggable check its api. IE https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker#setdraggable

Mapbox custom marker is build by html element. If you want to change visual display of custom marker element, you should update Its inside html. For example, here are 2 functions I use to create a div with image background then return it as a image marker

```
    /**
     *  @function CustomMarkerWithIcon(): constructor for CustomMarker with image icon specify
     *  @param lnglat: (LngLat) position of the marker
     *            map: (Map) map used on
     *           icon: (image) object for custom image
     */
    function CustomMarkerWithIcon(lnglat, map, icon) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';
        el.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + icon.url + '")';
        el.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
        el.style.width = icon.size.width;
        el.style.height = icon.size.height;
        el.style.zIndex = icon.zIndex;

        return new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                    .setLngLat(lnglat)
                    .addTo(map);
    }


    /**
     *  @function ChangeMarkerIcon(): change marker icon
     *  @param marker: (marker) marker
     *           icon: (image) object for custom image
     */
    function ChangeMarkerIcon(marker, icon) {
        var el = marker.getElement();
        el.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + icon.url + '")';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  However this answer is not helpful to me because it does not solve my problem of how do I set the draggable property of a specific marker after it has been added to the map.

Comment: Hi, I think It is quite simple because Mapbox has `setDraggable` function (I mention it on first part of my answer). Look in your question, I think you don't store reference to marker after you add it to map so you have trouble to call `setDraggable` and you try to find something like `map.getMarker('dog')` which doesn't exists. It is better, If you can post your code here that help stackoverflow user easily give you answer

Answer (score 0):

You're right: Mapbox GL JS [doesn't store references to markers](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5821#issuecomment-356704579). However, you can store your own references to the markers in an array at the time that you generate them.

In this example below, I am looping over a set of GeoJSON point features and creating a custom HTML marker for each:

```
let markersArray = [];

geojson.features.forEach(feature => {
  // create a HTML element for each feature
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.className = "marker";
  el.innerHTML = `
    <img src="custom-marker.png" height="20px" width="20px" />
    <span class="marker-label">${feature.properties.name}</span>
  `;

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
    element: el,
    anchor: "top"
  })
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);

  // add to my own array in an object with a custom 'id' string from my geojson
  markersArray.push({
    id: feature.properties.id,
    marker
  });
});
```

This `id` string can be whatever you want. You can even store other parameters if you want to be able to query other things, like latitude/longitude:

```
markersArray.push({
  id: feature.properties.id,
  coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
  marker
});
```

Then, if I want to access the marker's instance members (like [`setDraggable`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker#setdraggable)), I can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return the first instance that matches my search parameters in `markersArray`:

```
let someIdQuery = "some-id";

let queriedMarkerObj = markersArray.find(
  marker => marker.id === someIdQuery
);
queriedMarkerObj.marker.setDraggable(true);
```

(Note that `Array.find()` just returns the first instance in the array that matches your condition. Use something like [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you want to be able to query for more than one marker.)