# How to turn on/off draggable property on custom image markers in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, markers

After adding custom image markers using the Marker.addTo() method there doesn't seem to be a way to query the markers to dynamically set the draggable property on/off.  There is no way to get a collection of markers added to a map.  Please help!

I don't see a .getMarker() method on the map object nor do I have access to the collection of custom image markers added to the map.  Is there any other method besides Markers to add custom photo images to the map and control them?

I see plenty of great examples using symbols, etc but I need to use custom images for each marker.

I would like to add photo thumbnails on a map and query them by name or id to update their draggable state on/off in realtime.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Marker Feature Instance in MapBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037503/get-marker-feature-instance-in-mapbox)

Answer (score 0):

may I know what framework are you using ,and you can use geojson to add multiple markers, and can define draggable as a property in geoJson and alter it if you are are using JS or just define the property as a state variable in react and play with it accordingly.